# Autocomplete using data table

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have researched this and I am stuck. The following code will write to the console with the values from the database that match the typed characters. However I can not get the values into the field where they should go. I know I have that part correct. The error I get when trying replacing the console.log with return{value.nameVal} is '.' unexpected token. With return{value: nameVal} I get nameVal is not defined. With just return{nameVal} I get nameVal is not defined.

How do I get the values into the autocomplete field?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $( "#ingredVal" ).autocomplete({
            source: function(request,response){
            
            $.post("./cfcs/ingredients.cfc?method=getIngredName&json=1&text="+$("#ingredVal").val(), function(data){
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                $.each(obj,function(key,value){
                    console.log(value.nameVal);
                     
                });
            });
          } 
        });

    });
```

Comment: Hi, you can try like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/sty9nup2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer provided by Swati is below. I'm putting it here in case the link to the fiddle answer becomes broken.

$(document).ready(function(){

```
    $( "#ingredVal" ).autocomplete({
        source: function(request,response){
        $.get("./cfcs/ingredients.cfc?method=getIngredName&json=1&text="+$("#ingredVal").val(), function(data){
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);

            const result = [];

            $.each(obj,function(key,value){

                result.push({
                    label: value.name,
                    value: value.nameVal
                });
                response(result); 


            });
        });
    }   
    });

});
```